# Regex is not working as expected in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have created a regular expression for Name validation where only “_”, “-“, “‘“, “. “ allowed.

Here is regular expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_']{1,24}$
```

Problem is this its allowing name having `@`, Check [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nxry52L2/1/):

```
var str = "deepak@";
var str2 = "@@";
alert(str.match("^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]{1,24}$"));//allowing why?
alert(str2.match("^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]{1,24}$"));//not allowing
```

Expected: Name having `@` should not allow.

Note: When i tested this regex in https://regex101.com/#javascript its working good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget to use regex delimiter in Javascript:

```
alert(str.match(/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]{1,24}$/));
```

Or even better:

```
alert(str.match(/^[a-zA-Z][\w'.-]{1,24}$/));
```

[**Updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nxry52L2/2/)

Answer (score -1):

I guess this would do the same:

```
str.match(/^\w{1,24}$/);
```

**Definition:**

*The \w metacharacter is used to find a word character.
A word character is a character from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore) character.*

Comment: You allow digits at the beginning of the string.